# Should we do anything about the related "moshiach job description" questions?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

We have several overlapping questions (not *precisely* duplicates) that cover the same territory.  To save people regenerating the answer anew each time a new question is asked, should we do anything to tie these together and if so what?

- [will the Messiah be the greatest torah scholar of the generation?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/37570/472) (the newest one)
- [Who is Moshiach?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10599/472)
- [Are the Jews today still waiting for the Messiah to come?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26938/472)
- [Why a human Messiah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22271/472)
- [Will the king messiah be a prophet?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22814/472)
- [Why don't Jews think Jesus is the messiah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8857/472)

(This list is the cumulative result of my seeing one of these, saying "haven't we had this before?", and adding my search results in comments.  I've probably missed some.)

All are tagged [messiah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/messiah) (correctly so).  They are but a few of the questions on this topic.  Does this "who is the moshiach / what are the job qualifications / how do we know it's him" cluster within the tag merit some sort of linking/sub-tagging/something else, and if so what?

Comment: related http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1299/759

Comment: Is there a way mark a question as a quasi-duplicate?

Comment: @BabySeal nothing within the software; comments with links to related questions seem to be the common approach, or sometimes links are included in a question directly (as part of explaining why *this* question is different from *that* one).  But that doesn't cover the whole cluster, just one or two.

Comment: @BabySeal care to write an answer to this question?  If it includes a cut/paste-able comment for people to use, so much the better.

Comment: This question, in a more general sense is asking whether or not we should try to be more methodical about linking related questions to one another, as opposed to haphazard "related" comments, here and there. Maybe a broader question should be asked/ volunteers be sought to compile mini lists of related questions?

Comment: @BabySeal good point.  I asked about this cluster because I ran into it and can't, offhand, remember seeing another cluster this big.  That doesn't mean they aren't out there.

Comment: I know I have asked strings of 2-3 questiosn that are higly related, but I can take care of those myelf :)

Answer (score 1):

Currently people link (subsets of) the list in comments, when we notice and think of it.  [This answer](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2044/472) (which expands the set of questions, thanks) makes it pretty clear to me that we wouldn't be able to link all of them in one comment (too long), and anyway it would be hard to maintain.

Perhaps instead we should comment with a link here instead (specifically a link to that answer), and keep the list up to date.

Comment: That will also be cleaner.  The comments are cumbersome.  And unclear to people who haven't read this post why they are there.

Answer (score 0):

Posting links to questions in comments already does this to an extent, bringing up linked questions on the side of the viewed question. This can be done by clicking the 'edit' tab of this post, highlighting all of the links that have been compiled by Monica and myself, and linking them in comments as space allows. This is preferable in my mind, because it provides a resource for related questions without invading actual question space. Use this comment text, by clicking the edit button, copying it and pasting it in a comment. (This appears to generally link all questions and list them in the 'linked' bar, from just one comment on one question, but if a user notices that this is not happening when it should be, this is available to them):

[will the Messiah be the greatest torah scholar of the generation?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/37570)
[Who is Moshiach?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10599)
[Are the Jews today still waiting for the Messiah to come?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26938)
[Why a human Messiah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22271)
[Will the king messiah be a prophet?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22814)
[Why don't Jews think Jesus is the messiah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8857)
[Who is Moshiach Ben Joseph and what does/did he do?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13359)
[Will Moshiach know that he is Moshiach?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/37585)
[Does Moshiach have to be a king?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/35312)
[Must Mashiach have Jewish ancestry, or just Davidic?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/37449)
[Can Moshiach be a woman?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/35296)
[Do we have to bring Mashiach?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/40607)

Alternatively a list of closely related questions could be added to the bottom of each question, separated by a break, like so:

---

### Highly Related questions

- [will the Messiah be the greatest torah scholar of the generation?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/37570/472)
- [Who is Moshiach?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10599/472)
- [Are the Jews today still waiting for the Messiah to come?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26938/472)
- [Why a human Messiah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22271/472)
- [Will the king messiah be a prophet?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22814/472)
- [Why don't Jews think Jesus is the messiah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8857/472)
- [Who is Moshiach Ben Joseph and what does/did he do?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13359/472)
- [Will Moshiach know that he is Moshiach?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/37585/472)
- [Does Moshiach have to be a king?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/35312/472)
- [Must Mashiach have Jewish ancestry, or just Davidic?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/37449/472)
- [Can Moshiach be a woman?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/35296/472)
- [What are the prophecies about messiah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/38921/472)
- [Do we have to bring Mashiach?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/40607/472)

Comment: @ also noticing that linking all these questions on one link brings them all up in linked bar of all linked questions, so one comment should do it, (Just went on a commenting spree and realized this). Correct me if I'm wrong..

Comment: That's by design, yes (though I'd forgotten it would happen until you mentioned it).

Comment: @MonicaCellio so its not working on all of them =/ right now "will Moshiach know.." only has 2 links. I posted again.