# What should we do about "why isn't X the messiah" questions?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

We've gotten several questions over the years asking why so-and-so can't be the messiah, most recently https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/79742/why-dont-jews-think-li-hong-is-the-messiah.  See also:

- https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/79226/why-dont-jews-think-muhammad-ibn-hasan-al-madhi-is-the-messiah (marked as a dupe of [Must Mashiach have Jewish ancestry, or just Davidic?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/37449/must-mashiach-have-jewish-ancestry-or-just-davidic))
- [Which prophecy in specific will Saoshyant not fulfill?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/76096/472) (deleted)
- [Do any Jews, ancient or modern, hold that Michael the Arch-angel is the coming messiah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/30789/do-any-jews-ancient-or-modern-hold-that-michael-the-arch-angel-is-the-coming-m?s=4|0.5113)

I thought there was one of these about Muhammad, but I can't find it.  Maybe I was misremembering [Is Muhammad a prophet?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/62533/is-muhammad-a-prophet)  (deleted).

I also thought I remembered more of these, but searching for "messiah" in all questions (including deleted ones) didn't turn them up.
The answer to *all* of these questions is going to boil down to "because X didn't fulfill the job requirements".  We have a high-quality Q&A about the most famous claimant, but [Why don't Jews think Jesus is the messiah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8857/why-dont-jews-think-jesus-is-the-messiah) goes beyond the general answer to address Christian claims, and I think it's valuable to have posts here that call that out for Googlers.

The Jesus question is usually proposed as a duplicate of the others, but because that question isn't *just* "didn't fulfill the job requirements" but adds more, it doesn't feel like a great fit as a dupe target.

Do we want to nonetheless close other questions as a dupe of that one?  Should we write a canonical Q&A that also links to the Jesus question for more on that one specific claim?  Should we do something else?

Related, but not the same as this question: [Should we do anything about the related "moshiach job description" questions?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2026/should-we-do-anything-about-the-related-moshiach-job-description-questions)

Comment: Linking the Mohamaed one and the others together in this post will probably end up being useful.

Comment: @DoubleAA hmm, I *thought* we had a Muhammad one, but I couldn't find it.  (Well, one about a *different* Muhammad, but that's not the one I meant.)  I edited in some links.

Comment: This looks like a special case of http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3784/what-should-we-do-with-does-judaism-permit-this-random-special-case-that-i-won . That's not to say that a particular strategy, e.g. a canonical dupe-target wouldn't be worthwhile.

Comment: Why isn't it simply comparative religion; a question that presupposes knowledge about a different religion?

Comment: @mevaqesh If it doesn't explain more about the person in question, it could well be comparative religion.